# #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near :(

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

I try to upload my backup SQL ( 10 days ago ) and get the following error:

```
Error
SQL query:

INSERT INTO `tlc_2_icl_strings` (`id`, `language`, `context`, `name`, `value`, `string_package_id`, `type`, `title`, `status`, `gettext_context`, `domain_name_context_md5`) VALUES
(339, 'en', 'us', 'ff242757e5c1e721795821ecbb4faa47', 'Menu Hover Text Color', NULL, 'LINE', NULL, 0, '', 'd17598730ad5b89d5156deab80901e2c'),
(340, 'en', 'us', 'cc5873ef6cc4407707d02137e62bca9c', 'Dropdown Background Color', NULL, 'LINE', NULL, 0, '', '6bc21a9c11719c10eb36ceaccde586d5'),
(341, 'en', 'us', '7438cef42306265c506b8c08ea81e169', 'Dropdown Text Color', NULL, 'LINE', NULL, 0, '', 'e3b512326d7eaf37193cc6d27acae76d'),
(342, 'en', 'us', 'bb38a8990bde7186a9f94d255f2c558b', 'Dropdown Hover Background Color', NULL, 'LINE', NULL, 0, '', '83dd52f7f96bcfb5677d842d86006ce7'),
(343, 'en', 'us', '5f71e49358bad1a47d34b1004ab9535f', 'Dropdown Hover Text Color', NULL, 'LINE', NULL, 0, '', '4de2db7c374f895b6d2e07b2e6490202'),
(344, 'en', 'us', '83a985eb08f189a5a39f866a9c8627a9', 'Dropdown Active Background Color',[...]
MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''cc348e437dc74681e343' at line 91
```

I don't know what to do! Thank you in advance...

Comment: This is almost certainly a typo.  Did you check for that data?

Comment: no really where can i check it? thank you

Comment: already fixed thank you.